# How to get both file size and filename in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to get both file name and file size of file uploaded via HTTP post.
i am able to get file using `get_file = request.POST['file'].file` and file name using `get_filename = request.POST['file'].filename` but when i do `get_file_size = os.stat(get_file).st_size` to get the size of the uploaded file it throws an error saying 
"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found"
So how i can get file size and check if same is less than 10Mb?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong `os.stat()` method takes file path as an argument and you are passing a file object to it.

Try using `os.fstat()` method. It takes File Descriptor as an argument.

Here's a working code you can use:

```
size = 0
fp = request.POST.get('file')
if fp is not None:
    file = fp.file
    if hasattr(file, 'fileno'):
        size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
```

Size of the file is in bytes.